# Mailchimp intergration error

Tags: php, mailchimp

We want to import all our database into one of your lists. We use php. The code is:

```
$api_key = "dXXXXXXX7eX276XXXXXXXX490";
$list_id = "7XXXb0XXXe";

$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp($api_key);
$Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists($Mailchimp);

$batch = array();
$batch[] = array('email' => array(
                                'email' => 'xxxgmail.com',
                                "euid" => "xxx@gmail.com",
                                "leid" => "xxx@gmail.com"
                            ), 
                 'merge_vars' => array('FNAME' => 'XXX'));

$subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->batchSubscribe($list_id, $batch, false, true, true);
```

But I get an error 
Mailchimp_User_DoesNotExist

Could not find user record with id

I tried many times, removed uuid and leid but no success. What is wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The API key used by me was incorrect.